# Set default global json serializer settings

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to set the global serializer settings like this in my `global.asax`.

```
var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```

When serializing object using the following code the global serializer settings are not used?

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(page))
};
```

Isn't it possible to set the global serializer settings like this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Setting the `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` did the trick.

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
```

Comment: i had to set ``GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings`` to the same object to ensure that this config would be used everywhere. (in this case: by webapi and manually invoking via JsonConvert)

Comment: This does not work at all. The settings are completely ignored.

Comment: Works perfectly. In my case it was an external library used from a ASP.NET Core project.
I added the following code to Startup (ConfigureServices)

Comment: By the way, maybe it's better to store singleton instead of running "new JsonSerializerSettings" every time? What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

Accepted answer did not work for me.  In .netcore, I got it working with...

```
services.AddMvc(c =>
                 {
                 ....
                 }).AddJsonOptions(options => {
                     options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                     ....
                 })
```

Comment: If you are doing any manual serialization/deserialization using JsonConvert, you will need to use the accepted answer above. So you will need to set both if you want consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following in your action so that you can return a content-negotiated response and also your formatter settings can take effect.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, page);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, are there any pros or cons by using `Request.CreateResponse` rather then creating a `new HttpResponseMessage` like I did in my solution?

Comment: yes, you would loose content-negotiation...for example, if a request comes for `application/xml`, you would still be sending back json data ...

Answer (score 1):

You're correct about where to set the serializer. However, that serializer is used when the request to your site is made with a requested content type of JSON. It isn't part of the settings used when calling SerializeObject. You could work around this by exposing the JSON serialization settings defined global.asax via a property.

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings
{
    get
    {
        return GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    }
}
```

And then use this property to set the serialization settings when doing serialization within your controllers:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(page, WebApiApplication.JsonSerializerSettings))
};
```