# Newtonsoft.Json customize date serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am using `Newtonsoft.Json` for serializing my dates from C# to JSON. What I want to do is have the json serializer use the current culture for formatting dates into string.

Here is what I am getting by my Json serializer:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now);
```

result is:

```
"2016-07-08T17:10:17.6722753-05:00"
```

But what I prefer is:

```
"08/07/2016 17:10:57"
```

Because my current culture is brazil and I want my dates to  be displayed the above way.

Is it possible to **Globally** (for any date that may be serialized) tell the json serializer in Newtonsoft.Json to use as if it is doing the `date.ToString()` (because ToString respects the culture in `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` and gives the right format accordingly)

Comment: You could set the [global serializer settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815759/set-default-global-json-serializer-settings) to use a thread-static value for the [`DateFormatString`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatString.htm).

Comment: How? Can you try to add some code. What should be the specific configuration I should make for my dates

Answer (score 49):

You'll want to set [JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateFormatString.htm) to your desired format.

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsonSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject, jsonSettings);
```

After that, you can either pass the settings object in each time you use the serializer, or follow the steps in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815759/set-default-global-json-serializer-settings) referenced by dbc. Although, you don't mention where this is running (ASP.NET, desktop, UWP, etc), so how you set it globally may differ.

Comment: I am using MVC6 do you know where I can place the code so that it applies to all json.I put it in startup.cs method configure but it is not working.

Comment: JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ... }

Comment: Use the following with 'HH' for 24-hour clock:

jsonSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss";

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a Converter in the JsonSerializer settings.

```
public class SpecialDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
    {
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
             writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
        }
    }

    string convertedDateTime = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now, Formatting.Indented, new SpecialDateTimeConverter());
```

Comment: Use the following with 'HH' for 24-hour clock: jsonSettings.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss";