# Added an hour on to parsed date

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm posting this to an ASP.net Core action...

```
{
   "Start":"2018-09-30T00:00:00+00:00",
   "Finish":"2018-10-01T00:00:00+00:00"
}
```

It models binds to two `Date?` properties but the values are the same date but the time is 1am.

Why might this be? It only seems to do it when the "+00:00" is present so my guess is that this represents Greenwich meantime, which the server is currently at +1 for summer time.

Comment: Hi Ian, I assume you are using a custom model binder; would you be kind enough to post the code that is parsing these?

Comment: I'm not using a custom model binder. I presume that what is running is the standard ASP.net Core model binder for dates.

Comment: I was afraid you’d say that... honestly you’d be better off passing the dates as strings to your controller and parsing them in code.

Comment: Seems to work ok if I replace "+00:00" with empty string when generating the JSON. Probably a safe way of doing this using a custom serializer with Newtonsoft JSON.

Comment: The other thing you can try is changing the model property types to DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I essentially used this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/38276403/221683

This custom formatter doesn't include the time zone in the date string.

```
public class DateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((DateTime) value).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
    }
}

var serializedItem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, new DateTimeConverter());
```