# Serialize list of objects with JSON.NET in C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a List that looks like:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
Product p1 = new Product(1, "Apple", new Description("Red Apple"))
Product p2 = new Product(2, "Banana", new Description("Yellow Banana"))
products.Add(p1);
products.Add(p2);
```

A product looks like this:

```
//Product model
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual Description descriptions { get; set; }

//Description model
public string description { get; set }
```

Now I want to serialize this `List<Product>` to JSON with JSON.NET. I've tried:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'Module' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.
```

I also have the following line in my `Startup.cs` file that should avoid loops:

```
xy.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Can I provide more/better informations? 
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Kindly provide all the datastructure in details with constructors.  Only thing is noticeable is `Product` constructor takes single `Description` so provide all necessary details.

Comment: Can you please tell something about the `Description`?

Comment: If your `Description` has a Product in it, try to add `[JsonIgnore]` in the variable, or if there is any objects that references the object itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Comment: @DanielB It's not the exact same issue, because I have another error that could not be solved in your post

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya It's just an example I tried to give that is near on my real project

Comment: @Thaun_ Thanks! Tried it, but didn't resolve my issue

Comment: Should u add to config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings?

Comment: Is xy.SerializerSettings for XmlSerialization?

Comment: @DanielB `xy.SerializerSettings` are for the JSON.NET...with that it *should* ignore the loops and normally don't throw this error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815759/set-default-global-json-serializer-settings

Comment: @DanielB THANKS! It works now! You wanna write that as solution and I approve it?

Comment: No problem. Done! @RaphaelM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `JsonConvert`'s default Setting rather than `SerializerSettings`:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
```