# Is it possible to use a JsonSerializer default option in a .NETCore Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, console-application

I have a .NETCore Console App and I am serializing/deserializing using the following option

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
                    {
                        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                        WriteIndented = true
                    };
```

Is there any way that I can inject `services.AddJsonOptions()` and use `Json.Text.Serializer` without passing all the time my serializeOptions? Do I need to create my own `SerializerWrapper` for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331479/how-to-globally-set-default-options-for-system-text-json-jsonserializer) or - "If you use JsonSerializerOptions repeatedly with the same options, don't create a new JsonSerializerOptions instance each time you use it. Reuse the same instance for every call. " - [system-text-json-configure-options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-configure-options?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: kind of, the thing is that most of these solutions are for web apps :( and the other one is to create your own wrapper as an extension method

Comment: mine is a console app

Comment: Are you using a `Host`? You can configure services in a console app the same way.