# System.Text.Json configuration inside Hangfire not recognized

Tags: asp.net, hangfire, system.text.json

In my Startup.cs I have **AddJsonOptions** with some options and some custom converters. It all works fine if I call API but if Hangfire fires a method that needs to serialize something where I used **JsonConverter** attribute, it doesn't recognize options I have in the Startup.cs for System.Text.Json.

Is there any way to configure System.Text.Json options so Hangfire recognizes them (mainly custom converters)? It's not an option for me to create JsonSerializerOptions as I'm not doing serialization myself myself.

Thanks

Comment: According to [How to use system.text.json with hangfire?](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-use-system-text-json-with-hangfire/9070) hangfire is still using Json.NET not System.Text.Json.

Comment: But even if it did, `AddJsonOptions()` only configures asp.net-core and does not affect direct calls to `JsonSerializer`, which does not support global settings at all. For confirmation see [Api proposal: Change JsonSerializerOptions default settings #31094](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094) and [How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331912).

Comment: Hangfire would need to add a method to set `JsonSerializerOptions` similar to [`Hangfire.Common.JobHelper.SetSerializerSettings()`](https://api.hangfire.io/html/M_Hangfire_Common_JobHelper_SetSerializerSettings.htm).

Comment: Thank you @dbc for explanation. So my main problem is that my configuration for serializer options doesn't actually affect Hangfire or as you say, direct calls to JsonSerializer but only for asp.net-core instance. Well hopefully Hangfire will resolve that in the future, but for now I'll try and search for some kind of workaround to achieve what I need. Thanks again @dbc!