# How to enforce a JSON serialization policy for EVERYWHERE in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I know that I can use this code to set a JSON policy in ASP.NET Core:

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        });
```

As you can see, I want the `DictionaryKeyPolicy` to be **camelCased**.

However, if I return a `JsonResult`, then this policy is not applied.

I know I can create a custom `MyJsonResult` to encapsulate this. But this means that I should make sure all of our developers use our custom JSON result.

I also know that I can create a helper class to return the policy object to me, but again this means that I should make sure all of our developers keep in mind to pass that object to `JsonResult` always.

However, the best way is to somehow apply this policy globally in a centralized place.

I want to know if it's possible to let ASP.NET Core understand that we want a global JSON serialization policy?

Comment: Not currently implemented with System.Text.Json, see [How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331479) and [Api proposal: Change JsonSerializerOptions default settings #31094](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094) for confirmation.