# AddJsonOptions doesn't work in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, system.text.json

I want to add global JsonSerializer options to use ReferenceHandler.Preserve, i can't configure my blazor server App to use it as a global setting for all json Serializers.

i used

```
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
        options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    });

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    });

builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(o =>
   {
       o.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
       o.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
   });
```

none of them works as expected the options doesn't change from the defaults and i keep getting the same exception: "The JSON value could not be converted to"
using the same options at each request works

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
var httpClient = _httpFactory.CreateClient("API");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _tokenProvider.JwtToken);
var result = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Manufacturer>>("manufacturer", options);
```

but i want to define the options for all requests without explicitly writing them each time.

Comment: Many apps provide default `JsonSerializerOptions` via some builder, but System.Text.Json does not have global default options that are modifiable.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331570/3744182) by Chris Yungmann to [How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331479/3744182).  Your best option would be to add some extension method to `HttpClient` that encapsulates your desired global options as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331912/3744182) by ps2goat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Named Client` you could use `Typed Client` (or even generated with `NSwag` or `Refit`) and handle `JSON` formatting options inside this typed API client.

E.g. `NSwag` API clients generator has [an option to generate](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/CSharpClientGeneratorSettings)  `UpdateJsonSerializerSettings` method which you can define in the base class for type dAPI client like:

```
internal class BaseClient
{
    protected static void UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(JsonSerializerOptions settings) => settings.ConfigureDefaults();
}

// generated API client: 
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NSwag", "13.16.1.0 (NJsonSchema v10.7.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
internal partial class SomeClient : BaseClient, ISomeClient
{
    private System.Net.Http.HttpClient _httpClient;
    private System.Lazy<System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions> _settings;

    public ActionsClient(System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _settings = new System.Lazy<System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions>(CreateSerializerSettings);
    }

    private System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions CreateSerializerSettings()
    {
        var settings = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions();
        UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(settings);
        return settings;
    }
    ... the rest of generated code has omitted 
}

// Extension which configures the default JSON settings (as an example): 
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    private static JsonSerializerOptions GetDefaultOptions() => new() { WriteIndented = true };

    public static JsonSerializerOptions ConfigureDefaults(this JsonSerializerOptions? settings)
    {
        settings ??= GetDefaultOptions();

        settings.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        settings.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        settings.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString;
        settings.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());

        return settings;
    }
}
```

Then you register on `DI` your `ISomeClient` typed client like this:

```
builder.Services
    .AddScoped<MyLovelyAuthorizationMessageHandler>()
    .AddHttpClient<ISomeClient, SomeClient>(httpClient => 
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiSettings.WebApiBaseAddress);
        // ...etc.
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<MyLovelyAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

And then - inject `ISomeClient` where you need it, and call methods with typed `DTOs` keeping all `JSON` serialization/deserialization magic under the carpet.

```
[Inject] private ISomeClient Client {get; set;} = default!;
```

Documentation: about [Typed Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api#typed-httpclient)