# System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_SerializerCycleDetected

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

I got this error:

```
JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.

    System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_SerializerCycleDetected
```

I've already added:

```cs
.AddJsonOptions(x =>
    {
        x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;   
    }
);
```

to the configuration, but this doesn't seem take effect.

The only way I can remove this error is adding the attribute `[JsonIgnore]` on the navigation properties of my models
but i'm sure i'm not applying `.AddJsonOptions` in the right place

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, PermissionPolicyProvider>();
    services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();
    services.AddNotyf(o =>
    {
        o.DurationInSeconds = 10;
        o.IsDismissable = true;
        o.HasRippleEffect = true;
    });
    services.AddApplicationLayer();
    services.AddInfrastructure(_configuration);
    services.AddPersistenceContexts(_configuration);
    services.AddRepositories();
    services.AddSharedInfrastructure(_configuration);
    services.AddMultiLingualSupport();
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddJsonOptions(x =>
                    x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;     //<-- **** added this
             );
    services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddTransient<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>();
}
```

or maybe the JSON serializer is configured correctly at controller level but the error is originated from another source?

Looking deeper in the stacktrace of the error it's generated from:

`await _distributedCache.SetAsync(cacheKey, anagReparto);`
where
`_distributedCache` is `Microsoft.Extension.Caching.Distributed.IDistributedCache`

maybe this package needs a its own JSON configuration and don't use the controller's JSON serializer options that i've configured?

Comment: Can you share your model? Maybe we can omit reference loops from your class definitions as much as possible?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to help you.  E.g., do the classes that participate in the cycle have parameterized constructors?

Comment: *maybe this package needs a its own JSON configuration and don't use the controller's JSON serializer options that i've configured?* -- this may be true.  System.Text.Json [does not have modifiable global options at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331479) so setting the asp.net options only affects asp.net and not any other library that happens to use System.Text.Json.