# System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize ignores global config

Tags: c#, serialization, polymorphism, blazor-webassembly, system.text.json

In a Blazor WASM app under .NET 7 I configure standard Json serializer options like so in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(options => {
  options.TypeInfoResolver = new PolymorphicAgentaDtoResolver();
  options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
});
```

Later on in a service of the App I want to serialize an object with `JsonSerializer.Serialize(...)`. The result doesn't use the defaults from above. My question is why the defaults aren't used.

If I inject `IOptions<JsonSerializerOptions>` via the constructor of the service and use them in the appropriate overload of `JsonSerializer.Serialize(...)` the result is correct.

Code

```
public async Task<List<ServiceauftragDto>> GetServiceAuftraege(AgentaDto dto) {
  string s = JsonSerializer.Serialize<AgentaDto>(dto);  // wrong
  s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto);                    // wrong
  s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto, dto.GetType());     // wrong
  s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto, dto.GetType(), injectedOptions.Value);    // correct
  s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto, JsonSerializerOptions.Default);   // wrong
  ...
}
```

Comment: What you’re saying in the builder is _hey, when you’re asked to inject serialization options, please inject these ones_ but this does **not** mean _always use these options when serialising_ so this is expected.

Comment: What you’re trying to do is change the default options, which isn’t possible (and is [‘not planned’](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094))

Comment: there are hacky ways using reflection - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331479/how-to-globally-set-default-options-for-system-text-json-jsonserializer - but I would be cautious about using those.

Comment: Server side does have `services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(...)`. That made me think `Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(...)` would do the same for my client side code ;-) So the standard approach would be to `Configure<JsonSerializerOptions>(...)`, then inject them everywhere and use the appropriate overload of `JsonSerializer.Serialize(...)` with the injected options, right? Again, thank you!