# builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions> not being called in Top Level Statements / Minimal API project

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm trying to set serialization options for System.Text.Json in a top-level statements project.
I'm doing something wrong in that the callback passed to Configure doesn't appear to be called.
Can someone please set me in the right direction?
Thanks

```
 using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateSlimBuilder(args);
    
    builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This doesn't appear to be called.
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals;
    });
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Ok(new{value=double.PositiveInfinity}));
    
    app.Run();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331479/how-to-globally-set-default-options-for-system-text-json-jsonserializer)

Answer (score 0):

This worked. The issue was using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals;
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Ok(new { value = double.PositiveInfinity }));

app.Run();
```