# Adding System.Text.Json custom JsonConverters globally in console app

Tags: c#, console-application, system.text.json

I'm converting our C# / .NET 7 codebase from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json. I have created custom JsonConverters that I want to register globally for each application. For our ASP.NET Core web apps it's straightforward:

```
var mvcBuilder = services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        foreach (var converter in jsonConverters)
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(converter);
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    });
```

However, for our console apps and windows services I'm not seeing a way to apply the System.Text.Json properties and add converters globally. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no global default for `JsonSerializerOptions`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58331570/3744182) by Chris Yungmann to [How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331479/3744182) which is still correct as of .NET 7.  The question has several answers suggesting workarounds.

Comment: MSFT has explicitly declined to implement global defaults for `JsonSerializerOptions`.  See [Api proposal: Change JsonSerializerOptions default settings #31094](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094#issuecomment-1235451167): *Per previous discussions in this thread, we don't plan on making JsonSerializerOptions.Default mutable in future releases.*