# Configurating STJ serializer options in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, system.text.json

I have a ASP.NET Core 8 application that uses Razor pages. The endpoints internally use a HttpClient to get data from a downstream API.

The downstream API is configured to serialize enums as strings and I am trying to globally configure the receiving application to deserialize those strings into enums.

In my Program.cs I have:

```cs
using MvcJsonOptions = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions;

builder.Services.Configure<MvcJsonOptions>(o =>
{
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

In the Razor Page, I have the following code,

```cs
var objectWithEnumProperty = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<ObjectWithEnumProperty>($"some/uri", cancellationToken);
```

but it fails to deserialize the enum.

The current workaround is to define something like this in the same page model class

```cs
private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions JsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
};
```

and pass it to the HttpClient call

```cs
var objectWithEnumProperty = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<ObjectWithEnumProperty>($"some/uri", JsonOptions, cancellationToken);
```

While trying to solve the issue, I also added:

```cs
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.WriteIndented = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment();
    options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    options.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

but I think that this is for Minimal API endpoints.

Comment: System.Text.Json doesn't have global default options, see [How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331479/3744182) as well as [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094#issuecomment-1235451167).  `builder.Services.Configure<MvcJsonOptions>( ... )` only sets options for model binding and formatting for your web application, it doesn't configure global default options which will be used by `HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsync()` because there are no global options.  In fact this looks like a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @dbc thanks for your answer. If you add it as a answer, I will accept to future readers' advantage.