# Set system.text.json.jsonserializer globally minimal api

Tags: c#, json, .net-8.0, minimal-apis

I'm using .NET 8 minimal API.
I want to set the system.text.json.jsonserializer globally.

i don't want to pass the defaultSerializerSettings each time.

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this string json)
    {       
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, defaultSerializerSettings);
    }
```

Please take a look at this url.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331479/how-to-globally-set-default-options-for-system-text-json-jsonserializer
```

what i was trying to do:

```
This seemed to work for me, in StartUp.ConfigureServices:

services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy=JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    });
```

and it's not working with the minimal api.

i need the same thing with the minimal api

its not working with the minimal api

```
.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => {
      options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigureHttpJsonOptions` and `AddJsonOptions` manage serilizer settings for model binding/response serialization, they will not affect the settings you use to deserialize manually. Provide settings for `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`, for example:

```cs
var res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast[]>(responseContent, 
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });
```

**Notes**

1. There is no need to explicitly configure JSON options for API to only set the `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` to `true` since `JsonSerializerDefaults.Web` [defaults to `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/configure-options?pivots=dotnet-8-0):

   > The following options have different defaults for web apps:
   >
   > - `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true`
   > - `JsonNamingPolicy = CamelCase`
   > - `NumberHandling = AllowReadingFromString`
2. You can resolve configured JSON options from the DI. For example for minimal APIs (or you can configure your own and resolve them):

   ```
   app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", (IOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions> opts) =>
        {
            var serOpts = opts.Value.SerializerOptions;
            // ...
        });
   ```
3. You should not need to deserialize data to just serialize it back again (in the shown code at least). Returning content should do the trick: `return Results.Content(responseContent, "application/json");`
4. You can't mutate default serialization options ([see this github comment for example](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094#issuecomment-1235451167)), at least ATM, but you can define helper/extension methods which will use some global statically defined ones.

Comment: I know I can pass options, but imagine that I have 1000 endpoints.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the settings everywhere, consider using DI: add one configured setting as service, inject where needed and use that

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes, was adding update about using DI here (among other options).

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky If you have 1000 endpoints, the answer is to refactor the shared fetching logic out into a single seperate service they can all call, so you only have one, not 1000.

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky 1) arguably your problem has nothing to do with endpoints 2) please checkout the updates (notes).

Comment: i want to use the builder like in .net 6

Comment: i dont want to use the options in 1000 places in the code

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky what do you mean by "builder like in .NET 6"? This code AFAIK should work exactly as in .NET 6 AFAIK.

Comment: builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    });

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky this shouldn't affect manually called JsonSerializer.Deserialize neither in .NET 6 nor in .NET 8.

Comment: i dont want to use 
var res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast[]>(responseContent, 
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });

every time

Comment: i want it to be set in the builder, like newtonsoft use to be

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky _"like newtonsoft use to be"_ - but `AddNewtonsoftJson` does not configure `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` behavior too. Can you please explain your actual problem? Or provide a full [mre], including the full setup with  "builder like in .NET 6" showing what have worked for you and what does not.

Comment: instead of using this code each time
var res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast[]>(responseContent, 
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    });

i want to configure it in the builder just ones, so when i use  JsonSerializer.Deserialize i dont need to provide PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true, the options each time

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky it is not possible. AFAIK the same is true for Newtonsoft and JsonConvert (via builder), but it supports modification of global settings, unlike System.Text.Json.

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky note that it is possible to configure options once, but you still will need to resolve them and pass to the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` call and this option is shown in the answer.

Comment: "but you still will need to resolve them and pass to the JsonSerializer.Deserializ" this is what i don't want to do, it used to be possible before

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky please show the code where it was possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331479/how-to-globally-set-default-options-for-system-text-json-jsonserializer  "This seemed to work for me, in StartUp.ConfigureServices:" is not working for me in minimal api

Comment: @VadimTomashevsky what is "this"? Which answer exactly?

Comment: "This seemed to work for me, in StartUp.ConfigureServices:"

.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => {
      options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
})

and also Configure<JsonOptions> is not working with minimal api