# Blazor Web App: Problems with Json Reference Loop

Tags: c#, blazor, syncfusion, system.text.json, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor WebApp in which I load data with EF Core. Now I get the following error when displaying the data on a page because of reference loops, the data is loaded in an Syncfusion ComboBox:

```
<SfComboBox TValue="Contact" TItem="Contact" @bind-Value="item.Owner" DataSource="Contacts" Placeholder="Besitzer">
                            <ComboBoxFieldSettings Value="@nameof(Contact.FullName)"></ComboBoxFieldSettings>
                        </SfComboBox>
```

The traceback:

```
Error: System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Items.Owner.Items.Owner.Items.Owner.Items.Owner.Items.Owner.Items
...
...
JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.Serialize(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& rootValue, Object rootValueBoxed)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteString[TValue](TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo`1 jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.SfDropDownList`2.GetDataByValue(TValue ddlValue)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.SfDropDownList`2.InitValueAsync()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.SfDropDownList`2.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.SfComboBox`2.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

I have tried to set to Json Reference Handler but it does not work:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(options => options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
{
    jsonOptions.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
});
```

Classes used:

```
public class Item
{
    public Contact Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
}
```

Comment: To help you we will likely need to see a [mcve] showing your `Items.Owner` data model. Note that `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` has some [documented limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references#preserve-references-and-handle-circular-references) including *This feature can't be used to preserve value types or immutable types* so possibly your `Items.Owner` object falls under the limitations.

Comment: i have added the parts of the data model

Comment: When I serialize your data model directly with `ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve` it serializes successfully with no exception, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/mrEhOK.  Are you calling `JsonSerializer.Serialize()` directly, or is the framework invoking it for you?  If you can't share a [mcve] might you please [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, full traceback (from your main method) and inner exception(s), if any?

Comment: Is the data send from the API? Are you using Minimal APIs for that API?

Comment: I use the data directly in the Blazor WebApp Page, no API inbetween.

Comment: I don't know SyncFusion at all, but it might not be using the AspNetCore configured JSON options.  The page [How do I serialize and deserialize JSON in a Blazor application?](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/how-do-i-serialize-and-deserialize-json-in-a-blazor-application) shows manual direct calls to System.Text.Json.  Keep in mind that System.Text.Json [has no global mutable options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331479) and so each library will have its own default options (or none at all).  If you are calling the serializer directly you must pass in the options yourself.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].