# Why is camelcasing with Newtonsoft Json not working without serializer?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I have an object that I want to serialize to JSON and use camelcase. 
I have a .Net Core 3 Web Api application and in my startup file I have the following service registrations:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
});
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
var js = JObject.FromObject(obj);
```

Now, the result of this serialization is something like:

```
{
 StartRow: 1,
 EndRow: 2
}
```

When I instantiate a JsonSerializer, and pass it as the second argument, then I get the expected camelcase format:

```
{
 startRow: 1,
 endRow: 2
}
```

Here is the code:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer()
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };
var js = JObject.FromObject(obj, serializer);
```

This would mean I have to have a serializer for each controller.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something or registering something wrongly.

Thank you.

Comment: Your service registration configures how Web API serializes JSON objects in HTTP requests and responses. It doesn't affect the static `JObject.FromObject` method.

Comment: If you want to set serializer setting globally see [Set default global json serializer settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21815759/3744182).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //do your stuff..
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };
    //do your stuff..
}
```

Reference:

[Serializing a PascalCase Newtonsoft.Json JObject to camelCase](https://andrewlock.net/serializing-a-pascalcase-newtonsoft-json-jobject-to-camelcase/)