# Modifying how JSON.Net handles serializing a class, without direct access to JSON.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, webforms, json.net

I am working on a very old, but very large and very active **ASP.NET webforms** site, that uses a [custom Session State provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178587(v=vs.100)) that relies on **JSON.Net**.

One side effect of this is that objects that are based on plain, non-generic `IEnumerable` can be put in `Session`, but not retrieved from it. This is a **JSON.Net** limitation (an exception will be thrown if you try.)

Stripped of its details, my situation is this:  I need to stash an object in `Session`, of a third-party-provided, sealed class, for which I don't have the source code, that's based on `IEnumerable`. (We'll call it `VendorClassA`.)

And: I need to be able to get it out again.

**And that's what doesn't work.**

I have tried mapping an instance of `VendorClassA` to something else, stashing *that* in `Session`, and then converting it back. That works quite well.

But it turns out that there's one place -- within the third-party, inaccessible code -- where an instance of `VendorClassA` is retrieved from `Session`, and if it can't be retrieved, or if the retrieved object can't be cast to `VendorClassA`, a fatal exception is thrown.

```
VendorClassA value = (VendorClassA) HttpContext.Current.Session["key"];
```

I can't change that code (third-party, no source code, etc.)

And I can't modify the code that does the actual **JSON.Net** serialization, to change which methods are invoked, or how, because that's deep in the custom session state provider. Which I have no access to, both programmatically and organizationally.

**So, my question:**

Is there any way I can affect how **JSON.Net** handles this *specific* class's serialization, given that I can't change any of the following:

- That the object I put into Session State needs to be an instance of `VendorClassA`, or at least castable to it, because code I can't change will try to cast it to `VendorClassA`.
- The attributes on `VendorClassA`
- That it's based on plain, non-generic `IEnumerable`.
- That `VendorClassA` is sealed
- How the **JSON.Net** serialization routines are called and what parameters or overloads they use.

Perhaps there's some way to introduce a custom contract for `VendorClassA`, that would be globally applicable, but which could be introduced from a distance?

Is there a better way?

Comment: How that object is retrieved from the session? You say "That the object needs to be an instance of VendorClassA, or at least castable to it", but don't you specify exactly what type you (that third party library) want? That is - JSON.NET should know to which type to deserialize to.

Comment: @Evk What I meant by that line: there's a place in the 3rd party code that looks like this: `VendorClassA value = (VendorClassA) HttpContext.Current.Session["key"];`

Comment: So, whatever I get out of session has to be something that's castable to `VendorClassA`. If I put in a custom object (as I describe doing in paragraph 6), this line of code will fail.

Comment: I don't know exactly how the Session State provider uses JSON.Net, but it seems to be able to serialize/deserialize most objects, so presumably the original type is being passed to the serializer, somewhere deep in the Session provider code.

Comment: Try using `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` to set a custom converter for `VendorClassA`.  See: [Set default global json serializer settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815974/3744182).  This will work if your 3rd party code uses `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` or `JsonSerializer.CreateDefault()` but will not work if your third party uses `JsonSerializer.Create()` or `new JsonSerializer()` directly.  Since there's no [mcve] we have no way of knowing which the 3rd party library uses, but you can test it yourself and you may get lucky.

Comment: Assuming `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` works at all, your options are to inject a custom converter or custom contract resolver for `VendorClassA`.  Probably a custom converter is the way to go, see [JSON.net ContractResolver vs. JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41088492/3744182) for a discussion of when to use each.

Comment: @dbc  Thank you!  I'll give that a try!

Comment: Did `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings` work?  If not, might you please [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?

Comment: Hi, @dbc. What's happened is that I've abandoned this project. There were other problems with it that would have made any working solution brittle and full of code smells. (See [C#: Writing an explicit cast operator for an internal class in another .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394587/c-writing-an-explicit-cast-operator-for-an-internal-class-in-another-net-asse), which is a doozy. )

Comment: @dbc I have started a new one that has the same functionality goals, but is all custom code, and therefore doesn't need to interact with `VendorClassA`, or with vendor code at all.

Comment: @dbc But, since yours was the approach I was going to try, and you did answer the question, if you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Rather than answering, I went ahead and marked it as a duplicate.